# GPS location printing with only 6 decimal places instead of 8?

Tags: python-3.x, gps

I'm looking to print the latitude and longitude with high accuracy (will figure out RTK later). I know from using u-center there are 8 numbers after the decimal place coming from the module.

When I print the raw $GNRMC data in python on VSCode there are 7:

```
import serial

try:
    gps = serial.Serial('com5', baudrate=9600)

    while True:
        ser_bytes = gps.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        data = decoded_bytes.split(",")
        if data[0] == '$GNRMC':
            print(data)
        

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard Interrupt")
```

output:

> ['$GNRMC', '...', '...', '0012.34567', '...', '00012.34567', '...', ...]

When I run the code below there are 6:

```
import serial

try:
    gps = serial.Serial('com5', baudrate=9600)

    while True:
        ser_bytes = gps.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        data = decoded_bytes.split(",")
        if data[0] == '$GNRMC':
            lat_nmea = (data[3],data[4])
            lat_degrees = float(lat_nmea[0][0:2])
            if lat_nmea[1] == 'S':
                lat_degrees = -lat_degrees
            lat_minutes = float(lat_nmea[0][2:])
            lat = lat_degrees + (lat_minutes/60)
            lon_nmea = (data[5],data[6])
            lon_degrees = float(lon_nmea[0][0:3])
            if lon_nmea[1] == 'W':
                lon_degrees = -lon_degrees
            lon_minutes = float(lon_nmea[0][3:])
            lon = lon_degrees + (lon_minutes/60)
            print(lat,lon)
        

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard Interrupt")
```

output:

> 00.123456 000.123456

I'm not sure why they are being trimmed, or perhaps they're being rounded up?. How can I avoid this and include them in the output?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: You have a float, so you should just format the float to the number of digits you want. (your question is not about coordinates, but about float, and this fact may help you to search for solutions). There are many way to format strings: google it

Comment: I see. Thanks. I used: 

print("%0.8f" % lat, "%0.8f" % lon)

It seems to be working.